# Computation - dominated convergence theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following equality:

> $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(u)e^{-2\pi im u} du =\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)e^{-2\pi im u}$

From my notes I can see that these two are equal because of the dominated convergence theorem. However I've hard time understanding why this isn't "trivial".

**My question:** Why do we have to use the dominated convergence theorem?

> $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(u)e^{-2\pi im u} du = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{N} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(u)e^{-2\pi im u} du + \sum_{n=-1}^{-N} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(u)e^{-2\pi im u} du \right] = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left[ \int_{0}^{N+1}f(u)e^{-2\pi im u} du + \int_{-N}^{0}f(u)e^{-2\pi im u} du \right] = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)e^{-2\pi im u} $

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last step you use that

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{-N}^N f(u) e^{-2\pi \imath m u} \, du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u) e^{-2\pi \imath m u} \, du.$$

Since the integrals are Lebesgue integrals, this requires that $f$ is integrable, i.e.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(u)| \, du < \infty,$$

otherwise this equality might not hold true. *If* $f$ is integrable, then the above identity follows indeed from the dominated convergence theorem.